# Implementing editing/deleting a comment on a post in the same post_detail page

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-class-based-views

I'm using django's class-based views, and have successfully implemented a form for posting a comment on the same page as the DetailView for my Post model.  I'm trying to implement an update/delete function for the comments, but I'm having trouble locating the specific comment using pk's.

What approach could I take to locate the specific comment and edit/delete it?
I would like the edit button to lead to a page with a form filled in with the current comment data, and the delete button to lead to a comment_confirm_delete.html template.  It would be awesome to edit the comment with a form on the same page, but I'm trying to get it working on a separate page first.

I found a lot of resources on how to do it using function-based views, but would like to use class-based views.

This is the urlpattern for comment delete (I haven't gotten to the update yet)

```
path('post/<int:pk_post>/comment/<int:pk_comment>/delete',CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment-delete')
```

This is in my views.py for the class that inherits DeleteView

```
class CommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        comment = Comment.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk_comment', ''))
        context['comment'] = comment
        return context

    def test_func(self):
        Comment = self.get_object()
        return self.request.user == comment.author
```

This is section in post_detail.html, where if the user is the author of the comment, the user can update/delete the comment.

```
{% if comment.author == user %}
  <a class="text-info small mr-1" href="#">Edit</a>
    <a class="text-danger small" href="{% url 'comment-delete' object.id comment.id %}">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```

I was hoping that by using two pk's (pk_post, pk_comment), I can locate the comment in the post and the DeleteView that the CommentDeleteView inherited from would do the job.  But I get the following error

AttributeError at /post/27/comment/9/delete
Generic detail view CommentDeleteView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

As the error indicates, the "comment.id" from the template was able to locate the specific comment, which makes me hopeful, but I can't figure out how to get around this error.  How can I use two pk's in tandem with the DeleteView for the comment?  Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score -1):

I think using 2 paths will not work. Try using one and functions rather than class.

Because class function of Django is limited. There is also Django package comment system.

I cannot think of the code but have you tried

please write under the class of detailview:
object.manager()

then write in the views:
comment = objects.all()

u.form = Post(instance = User, comment = comment)